# Out of range index

Tags: python, indexing, range

I am trying to make a program that will count the numbers in the list number, and would search for a sum of 10 in sequence_len numbers.
In the minute it gets a 10, it should stop.
1. With this code I have an error. what should I do?
     total=total+(list_n[i+n])
IndexError: list index out of range

2.I want the first for to be stop if Im finding a sum of then. Is it write to "break" at the end as I did or should I write i=len(list_n)?

```
number = 1234 
sequence_len = 2

list_n=[]
total=0
b="false"
list_t=[]

for j in str(number):
    list_n.append(int(j))

c=len(list_n)

for i in list_n:
    n=0
    while n<sequence_len:
        total=total+(list_n[i+n])
        n=n+1
    if total==10:
        b=true
        seq=0
        while seq>sequence_len:
          list_t.append(list_t[i+seq])
          seq=seq+1
        break
    else:
        total=0
    if b=="true":
        break 


if b=="false":
    print "Didn’t find any sequence of size", sequence_len
else:
    print "Found a sequence of size", sequence_len ,":", list_t
```

Comment: I didnot get the second part of the question clearly.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of errors. First with the basic:

```
b=true
```

This needs to the `True`, otherwise, python will look for the `true` variable.

Secondly, `i` actually contains the value of the variable for that iteration (loop). For example:

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> for i in l: print i
a
b
c
```

Because of this, you cannot use it as an index, as indexes have to be integers. So, what you need to do is use `enumerate`, this will generate a `tuple` of both the index *and* the value, so something like:

```
for i, var in enumerate(list_n):
    n = 0
```

An example of enumerate in action:

```
>>> var = enumerate([1,6,5,32,1])
>>> for x in var: print x
(0, 1)
(1, 6)
(2, 5)
(3, 32)
(4, 1)
```

And this statement should has logical problems I believe:

```
total = total + (list_n[i + n - 1])
```

If you want to get a sum of 10 from a list of numbers, you can use this brute-force technique:

```
>>> list_of_n = [1,0,5,4,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,2,7]
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> [var for var in combinations(list_of_n, 2) if sum(var) == 10]
[(5, 5), (4, 6), (2, 8), (2, 8), (3, 7), (4, 6), (8, 2)]
```

So, if you want a 10 from 3 numbers in the list, you would put `combinations(list_of_n, 3)` instead of `combinations(list_of_n, 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

When you say

```
for i in list_n:
```

`i` will not refer to the indices, but to the list elements themselves. If you want just the indices,

```
for i in range(len(list_n)):
```

`len(list_n)` will give you the size of the list and `range(len(list_n))` will give you a range of numbers starting from 0 and ending with `len(list_n) - 1`

Comment: I changed it but it still says "total=total+(list_n[i+n])" out of range

Comment: @user2923032 That is because of the while loop `while n<sequence_len:`. When `i` is pointing to the last element's index, you are trying to reach `list_n[i+n]`. What if `n` is `1` now? We are trying to access the list element which is out of its range, right?